# cannot open file libboost_thread-vc120-mt-1_55.lib

Tags: matlab, visual-c++, boost, linker-errors, mex

I installed the boost files and everything, but every time I run this program in matlab I get LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'libboost_thread-vc120-mt-1_55.lib'
I was able to link the boost directory in Visual Studio just fine, but it doesn't seem to be taking for the libs folder.

Comment: does your `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` environment variable points to the folder where boost lib files are?

Comment: @Shai `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` has no meaning on Windows. @user149478, LNK1104 is a link-time error, it happens when VC linker can't find a particular static library. Make sure you set correct linker paths in the VisualStudio *and* there is `libboost_thread-vc120-mt-1_55.lib` on this path. If you can't find the above file at all, perhaps you haven't built `Boost.Thread`?

Comment: @user149478: be more specific, are you compiling a MEX-function that links against Boost? That would be something like: `mex somefile.cpp -L"C:\path\to\libs" -lsomelib`

Comment: I had to link the boost path to get the other boost files to work, then I linked boost's lib path as well (which is where libboost_thread-vc120-mt-1_55.lib is.) I checked to make sure, and yes libboost_thread-vc120-mt-1_55.lib is in that path.

To be more specific the MEX function links against .h files that links against boost.

Comment: @user149478 you don't "link the boost path", it's an incorrect temr. Just add boost root path to the compiler paths, and the location of boost lib files to the linker paths - these are 2 separate items in VS project properties.